# My team member, whom I invited, is not getting an invitation

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams

I have created a new team and I am new to Stack Overflow Teams. My team member, whom I invited, is not getting my invitation. What is the procedure to send an invitation?

Comment: check the spam folder.